# Use Browserify + Knockout + Knockout projections

Tags: knockout.js, browserify, commonjs, browserify-shim, knockout-projections

I am trying to include both `knockout` and `knockout-projections` in a project with Browserify. I am using `browserify-shim` to bind it all together.

Unfortunately the `knockout-projections` code fails when it requires `knockout`, either with a compile-time error or a runtime error – depending on the setup of the shim.

To illustrate the problem I have set up a github repository: [brianmhunt/bshim-ko-testcase](https://github.com/brianmhunt/bshim-ko-testcase).

Comment: Man people love to use many plugins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@brianmhunt, still not an issue with browserify.

Your latest change on the repo installs both **knockout** and **knockout-projections** via bower.  That is fine.

However, each bower component also has a package.json.  This would not be an issue either, but the package.json file in **knockout-projections** specifies knockout as a dependancy as well.

Between the "browser" setting you have in your own package.json and **knockout-projections** also calling "require('knockout')" in its code, it's kinda of a catch-22 in this scenario.

A couple of workarounds:

- delete the package.json file in the **knockout-projections** directory
- run "npm install" in the **knockout-projections** directory  (see gotchas below)

Alternative: (install via npm):

> ```
> {
>   "name": "bshim-ko-test",
>   "version": "0.0.3",
>   "repository": "https://github.com/brianmhunt/bshim-ko-testcase",
>   "browser": {
>     "koproj": "knockout-projections"
>   },
>   "main": "./test.js",
>   "dependencies" : {
>     "knockout" : "~3.0.0",
>     "knockout-projections" : "SteveSanderson/knockout-projections"
>   }
> }
> ```

Now your steps will be:

- git clone `<repository>`
- npm install browserify -g
- cd `<repository>`, and "npm install"
- browserify test.js -o bundle.js

Gotchas:

- Be careful doing either second workaround above, or the alternate. 
  If your Knockout versions don't match, you get both copies of Knockout in bundle.js. Definately, not what your expecting.
- The package.json files in Knockout and KO Projections are pointing to debug files (not minified)
  This will make your bundle.js quite large.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head! Another alternative is to create an e.g. `vendor/` path and symlink to the script i.e. `ln -s bower_component/knockout/dist/knockout.js vendor/knockout.js`, then `"browser": "vendor/knockout.js"` ought to work as expected. I think the best choice is your suggestion to use `npm` to install the packages, but the symlinking may be an appealing alternative for some. Cheers.

Comment: Turns out there are a lot of packages that are only in bower, so symlinking it is. :)